# Getting duplicate fields when setting from Concrete class

Tags: java, concreteclass

I need to define constant values in each `ConcreteClass` that extends `AbstractClass`. For some reason object ends up having duplicate fields, one set of fields is equal to zeros, next one has proper values.

**SomeInterface**

```
public interface SomeInterface{
    double calculate();
}
```

**AbstractClass**

```
public abstract class AbstractClass implements SomeInterface{
       double x, y;

       public double calculate(){
            return x*y;
       }
    }
```

**ConcreteClass**

```
public class ConcreteClass extends AbstractClass{

    final double x = 1.1;
    public setY(double y){
        this.y = y;
    }

}
```

I need my concrete class to store constant value `final double x = 1.1;` while inheriting the `calculate()` method implementation from abstract class.

Comment: java does not allow overriding the instance variables. So, you can't do this unless you override calculate method in concrete class.

Comment: Java *does* 'allow' overriding the instance variables, it just may not have the effect you want.  But it's legal to do so.  I don't see what overriding the method has to do with the declaration of the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared x twice, so you get two x variables; one masks the other.  It's doing what you told it to.

To have the concrete class set a value, put the setting of it in a (or all) constructor(s) of the ConcreteClass.  Don't declare it again.

I don't know a way that you can declare it final and still alter it in a subclass.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to do something like this to get around - even though you cannot override instance variables in java.

If all you want to do is have Concrete class's have a constant variable, and the base abstract class use that for calculate method - You could try something like this..

```
public abstract class AbstractClass implements SomeInterface{

       double x, y;

    public void setX(double x){
        this.x = x;
    }
    public double calculate(){
        return x*y;
   }
}
```

Then in the concrete class you could still have the final variable and have that passed in to the abstract class's setter.

```
public class TestAbstractVariable extends TestAbstract {
    {
        final double x = 1.1;
        setX(x);
    }

    public void setY(double y){
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Thanks,
paul